Reference request for a theorem of Jaworowski
Jan Jaworowski, in 2000, proved the following theorem (I came to know about it from here)

Jaworowski (2000) : Let $Y$ be a finite simplicial complex of dimension $k$ and let $n\ge 2k$. If $f:S^n\to Y$ is a continuous map, then there is some $x\in S^n$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$

I have been trying to prove this theorem for sometime now and only have managed the following two cases : When $n\ge 2k+1$ (which follows from the classical Borsuk-Ulam theorem) and for $n\ge 2k$ when $H_k(Y,\mathbb Z_2)=0$ (which follows from looking at some $\mathbb Z_2$-index).
Ultimately, I think I am in need of some pointers now so I went hunting through the references. The original paper where I found the theorem links the paper "Periodic coincidence for maps of spheres" (Jan Jaworowski, Kobe journal of mathematics, 17(1):21–26, 2000). I have scoured the internet for this paper but have only found only three links pertaining to it :

A link to the review of the paper in the original journal.
The review itself.
A CiNii link

None of them have the paper or any access to it (or I might just be missing it).
I have tried to see if other people have proven the result, or mentioned other papers related to it. I have found one which is too sophisticated for just proving this result. For the sake of completeness, the paper is here. I have also come across this (this paper, also by Jaworowski and Izydorek, in fact sketches a proof for the second case I was able to solve).
I am currently at my wits end. Any help in finding a link to the paper (from where I can get access), a proof (even maybe a sketch) for the same, or anything pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.
